# Does Villager's pocket preserve velocity of Lloid rockets?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

When Villager first releases a Lloid rocket, it moves very slowly and then accelerates to a faster speed. If Villager pockets a Lloid rocket moving at full speed, when he releases the rocket will it still move at full speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if Villager pockets a Lloid rocket going at full speed, when he releases it the speed will be reset. It would be as if Villager just released the rocket for the first time: it will start slow and then accelerate to full speed.

This is because Villager's pocket resets projects to **base damage** before adding the damage multiplier. Resetting the Lloid rocket's damage also resets the speed, essentially forcing the projectile to start all over again.